# Is there a function where I can split text without splitting multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, split, list-comprehension

Right now I have a corpus that looks like this

```
Letter = EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')[3]
Scheherazade = EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')[4]
Maelstrom = EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')[5]
VonKempelen = EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')[6]
MesmericRevelation = EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')[7]
MValdemar = EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')[8]
TheBlackCat=EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')[9]
Usher = EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')[10]
```

and so on.

How do I write this into a list comprehension where I do not have to manually split it. Thank you!

For some context, I am trying to split a text. Each index is a new short story that is split by ('\n\n\n\n\n').

Comment: what does your sample look like?

Comment: It is a text, so by splitting each section, I get a short story. Each index is a short story split by ('\n\n\n\n\n').

Comment: is this what you're looking for? `splitStory = EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')` and then `Letter = splitStory[3];`    `Scheherazade = splitStory [4]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
split_short = EAPVol2.split('\n\n\n\n\n')

Letter,Scheherazade,Maelstrom,VonKempelen,MesmericRevelation,MValdemar,TheBlackCat,Usher = [split_short[i] for i in range(3,11)]
```